# If every convergent subsequece converges to the same limit then the sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, compactness

I came across this question:

In a compact metric space $(X,d)$ if every *convergent* subsequence of a sequence converges to the same limit, say $l$, then the original sequence also converges to $l$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose the sequence does not converge to $l$. Then $\exists$ an $\epsilon > 0$ such that for every $n_{0} \in \mathbb{N}, \exists n > n_{0}$ such that $d(x_{n},l) \geq \epsilon$. Thus, we get a subsequence $x_{n_{k}}$ such that $d(x_{n_{k}},l) \geq \epsilon$ for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Now using the compactness of the space, this subsequence has a convergent subsequence, say $x_{n_{k_{m}}}$, which cannot converge to $l$, however. But this subsequence is also a subsequence of the original subsequence and hence should converge to $l$. Hence the contradiction.