# Expected value convergence for sequence that converges in probability to zero

Tags: probability, measure-theory

My question goes as following. I have a sequence $X_n \xrightarrow{p} 0$ and $f$ is a bounded uniformly continuous function. Then I must show that $\mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \to f(0)$. My first idea was the following:

From continuity in zero of $f$, we have that $\exists \delta > 0$ such that $-\delta < x < \delta \implies f(0)-\varepsilon < f(x) < f(0)+\varepsilon$. Now let's define $A := \{|X_n| < \delta\}$, we the have that:

\begin{align*}
    \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] &= \int_{A} f(X_n) d\mu + \int_{A^C} f(X_n) d\mu \\
    &\leq \int_A (f(0)+\varepsilon) d\mu + \int_{A^C} f(X_n) d\mu \\
    &= (f(0)+\varepsilon)\mathbb{P}(|X_n| < \delta) + \int_{A^C} f(X_n) d\mu
\end{align*}
My problem now is that I can't make $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| < \delta) \to 1$ and the integral to zero simultaneously. The integral would go to zero when I would fix a certain $n$ and make $\delta \to 0$, but when I fix the $n$ I can't make $n \to \infty$ to make the probability go to one. Were I able to do this here, I would be able to show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] \leq f(0) + \varepsilon$ that would be for an arbitrary $\varepsilon > 0$ giving me $\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E}[f(X_n)] < f(0)$. Is there any way to go from this idea or should I try a new approach? I haven't used the bounded uniformity, but I have no idea how this might help me...

Comment: Doesn't it follow by the DCT ($f$ is bounded and continuous)?

Comment: Could you explain more? Doesn't DCT assume pointwise convergence? I have convergence in probability here...

Comment: Sure. But for any subsequence of $\{X_n\}$ there is a further subsubsequence converging a.s. to $0$.

Comment: I still can't understand how you would be using DCT. My sequence very well could be unbounded, but the unbounded part probability goes to zero... Also you would be showing only to a subsequence...

Comment: $Y_n=f(X_n)$ is a bounded sequence if $f$ is bounded... Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/461610/if-every-convergent-subsequece-converges-to-the-same-limit-then-the-sequence-con).

Comment: Got it. Thanks :)...